# c++ Transitioning from single source file to multiple files. error: 'blank' does not name a type

Tags: c++

I am currently attempting to write a very simple 2d game engine using SDL in order to help myself get more comfortable with coding. Unfortunately, I made the mistake of starting with a single source file, and now that my code is getting bigger, I am trying to split the existing code (which works fine before the split) into multiple header and source files. The first major issue I've encountered is that when I try to define SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_WIDTH, Window, and Renderer in init.cpp after declaring them in init.h, I get error: 'blank' does not name a type (blank being Window, Renderer, etc.). I am also trying to make them global, which may be part of the issue. Included below is the relevant code (I took out all the stuff I think is irrelevant in this case). I suspect I'm just missing something really simple here, but I've been unable to find an existing answer online like I have with my previous problems.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "globals.h"
#include "texture.h"

....
```

**globals.h**

```
#ifndef GLOBALS
#define GLOBALS

#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

#endif //GLOBALS
```

**texture.h**

```
#ifndef TEXTURE
#define TEXTURE

#include "globals.h"
#include "init.h"

....

#endif // TEXTURE
```

**texture.cpp**

```
#include "texture.h"

....
```

**init.h**

```
#ifndef INIT
#define INIT

#include "globals.h"

//screen dimensions
int SCREEN_WIDTH;
int SCREEN_HEIGHT;

//initiates SDL and creates a window and renderer
bool init();

//the created window
SDL_Window* Window;

//the renderer that will be used
SDL_Renderer* Renderer;

#endif // INIT
```

**init.cpp**

```
#include "init.h"

SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

Window = NULL;

Renderer = NULL;

bool init()
{
    bool success = true;
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO) < 0)
    {
        printf( "SDL was unable to initialize! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        success = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if( !SDL_SetHint( SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "1"))
        {
            printf( "Linear texture filtering not enabled!");
        }
        else
        {
            Window = SDL_CreateWindow( "Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
            if( Window == NULL)
            {
                printf( "Window could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
                success = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer( Window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
                if( Renderer == NULL)
                {
                    printf( "Renderer could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
                    success = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( Renderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
                    int PNGImage = IMG_INIT_PNG;
                    if( !(IMG_Init( PNGImage) & PNGImage))
                    {
                        printf( "Image loading not enabled! SDL_Image Error: %s\n", IMG_GetError());
                        success = false;
                    }
                    if( TTF_Init() == -1)
                    {
                        printf( "True type fonts not enabled! SDL_TTF Error: %s\n", TTF_GetError());
                        success = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return success;
}
```

I get the error in init.cpp at the top of the code before bool init()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Renderer = NULL;` is an assignment statement, which you cannot have in global scope. You can only have declarations in global scope. Since you have already declared `Renderer` in your header file, you don't need to redeclare it either. Just set it to null within one of your initialization functions (e.g. your current `init()` function).